# gd-text PHP library doesn't wrap text within box

Tags: php, gd

I'm using the [gd-text](https://github.com/stil/gd-text) PHP library to draw text on an image

It works but the text doesn't wrap within the boundary box I set if I don't provide whitespaces, here's my code:

```
$textbox = new Box($img);
$textbox->setFontSize(20);
$textbox->setFontFace('arial.ttf');
$textbox->setFontColor(new Color(255,0,0));
$textbox->setBox(
   10,  // distance from left edge
   10,  // distance from top edge
   10, // textbox width
   10  // textbox height
);
$textbox->setTextAlign('center', 'top');
$textbox->draw("my text my text my text my text my text my text");
```

The text wraps correctly but if I don't insert any whitespace then it doesn't. The text just keeps going outside the box. The documentation doesn't explain how to force the text to wrap even when no whitespaces are present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library only breaks at spaces, however it's pretty simple, I made a change that will break whenever you overrun the width of the box if your input string has no spaces. This change will only apply if the entire line has no spaces. Ideally there would be a mode that would wrap with no overflow. That would be pretty easy to add. You may also want to add a character to insert when a break occurs mid-word.

Replace the wrapTextWithOverflow method in the [Box](https://github.com/stil/gd-text/blob/master/src/Box.php) class with this:

```
protected function wrapTextWithOverflow($text)
{
    $lines = array();
    // Split text explicitly into lines by \n, \r\n and \r
    $explicitLines = preg_split('/\n|\r\n?/', $text);
    foreach ($explicitLines as $line) {
        // Check every line if it needs to be wrapped
        if((strpos($line, ' ')))
        {
            $words = explode(" ", $line);
            $line = $words[0];

            for ($i = 1; $i < count($words); $i++) {
                $box = $this->calculateBox($line." ".$words[$i]);
                if (($box[4]-$box[6]) >= $this->box['width']) {
                    $lines[] = $line;
                    $line = $words[$i];
                } else {
                    $line .= " ".$words[$i];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //If there are no spaces, append each character and create a new line when an overrun occurs
            $string = $line;
            $line = $string[0];

            for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
                $box = $this->calculateBox($line.$string[$i]);
                if (($box[4]-$box[6]) >= $this->box['width']) {
                    $lines[] = $line;
                    $line = $string[$i];
                } else {
                    $line .= $string[$i];
                }
            }
        }

        $lines[] = $line;
    }
    return $lines;
}
```